# How can i scale my character back after key is released

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my first day coding and this is the crouching code that I have come up with

```js
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl)) {
  Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
  scale.y = 0.1f; 
  transform.localScale = scale;
```

But after I release left control the scale stays the same but I need it to come back.

What should I do?

Comment: `if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl)){Vector3 scale = transform.localScale; scale.y = 1f; transform.localScale = scale;}` ? Or you could add a field to the class `Vector3 normalScale` then in `Start`: `normalScale = transform.localScale;` then in `Update`: `if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl)){transform.localScale = normalScale;}`

Comment: Please clarify your question. What exactly is calling this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add an `else` and make it return if you are not pressing.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
            scale.y = 0.1f; 
            transform.localScale = scale;
}
else
{//normal scale
}
```

I have used **GetKey** so if you hold the button it will shrink, if you leave it will go to its original size.

If you want to click 2 times to have the character to go to his start position you can declare a bool variable `crouch` and then

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl) && crouch == true)
        {
            Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
            scale.y = 0.1f; 
            transform.localScale = scale;
crouch = false;
}
```

And then under this

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl) && crouch == false)
        {
            // go back to normal size
crouch = true;
}
```

So if you keep pressing it will keep changing